# Child Object returns Null after Ajax Post

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am submitting some info using an Ajax post which is supposed to refresh a partial view. The info gets sent to the database however on return of the partial view, the Fees.Feetype data can't be rendered as it is null.

On manual refresh, the Fees.FeeType is rendered with no problem.

How do I get the FeeType to be included in the partial view after the ajax post?

Models

```
    public class Members
    {
        public virtual ICollection<Fees> Fees { get; set; }
    }
    public class Fees
    {
            public int FeeTypesId { get; set; }
            public virtual FeeTypes FeeType { get; set; }
            public virtual Members Members { get; set; }
    }
    public class FeeTypes
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FeeTypeName { get; set; }
    }
```

Ajax Post

```
            var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
            var postData = {
                __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                FeeOccurence: feeOccField.val(),
                FeeAmount: amountField.val(),
                FeeStatus: statusField.val(),
                FeeTypesId: typeField.val(),
                FeeDate: dateField.val(),
                MemberNo: memberNo
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Members/AddFees',
                type: 'POST',
                data: postData,
                success: function (members) {
                    alert(result);
                    $("#details").html(members);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                traditional: true
```

Controller

```
        public ActionResult AddFees (Fees fees)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Fees.Add(fees);

                db.SaveChanges();

                Members members = new Members();
                members = db.Members.Find(fees.MemberNo);

                return PartialView("~/Views/Members/_MemberDetails.cshtml", members);
            }
        }
```

Views

```
@model AccPortal.Models.Members
    <div class="col-md-7 md-fees" id ="details">
        @Html.Partial("_MemberDetails", Model)
    </div>
    //This is the partial view.    
        @model AccPortal.Models.Members
            @foreach (var item in Model.Fees)
            {
//The error happens on this line but all other Fees properties are rendered without issue.
                <td class="md-fee-value"data-type="status">@item.FeeType.FeeTypeName</td>
            }
```

Comment: Can I know are you binding only FeeType.FeeTypeName in your partial view or all the datas ?? And where is you _MemberDetails.cshtml partial view ?

Comment: I am only binding it in one place. _MemberDetails.cshtml is in ~/Views/Members/_MemberDetails.cshtml

Comment: My question is can u post your partial view code _MemberDetails.cshtml

Comment: I have edited the Views section to show which is the partial view

Comment: Check with my bellow code and let me know.

Comment: can you place a break point on members to check values

Comment: @BasantaMatia and are you getting  Fees.FeeType value on manual refresh ? or you are getting no value and no error

Comment: @Usman Fees.FeeType get the value on manual refresh. Only after ajax refresh, it has the error. The information is still stored correctly in the database

Comment: @Catfingers can you place break point on member to check values before returning

Comment: @Usman Hmm it seems Members.Fees[0].FeeType is a null object. Members.Fees[1].FeeType onwards is all fine. (checked by the breakpoint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check for `null` values before populating in the list to avoid `null exception`

```
 @model AccPortal.Models.Members
            @foreach (var item in Model.Fees)
            {
              if(item.FeeType != null)
                <td class="md-fee-value"data-type="status">@item.FeeType.FeeTypeName</td>
            }
```

because some data might be missing which is causing problem so with `if` condition it will populated only that data which is `not null`

Comment: This works. Now I have to find why the first record is null. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

These are the things you need to change in your code,

First, return a partial view with model from your Action method like this,

```
return PartialView("_MemberDetails", members);
```

`Datatype` should be html in your ajax method. So add this bellow line inside ajax method. You can add this line after this line `data: postData,`

```
dataType: "html",
```

Now in your ajax success method, change like this,

```
success: function (members) {
             //alert(result);  what is result here, that you have written
             $("#details").html(''); //first make it blank then render
             $("#details").html(members);
            },
```

In your partial view, you need to check whether FeeType is there or not before render the value,

```
@model AccPortal.Models.Members
@foreach (var item in Model.Fees)
 {  
  if(item.FeeType != null)
   <td class="md-fee-value"data-type="status">@item.FeeType.FeeTypeName</td>
  else
   <td class="md-fee-value"data-type="status"></td> //You can write NA here
 }
```

Comment: I have made the changes however the issue is still the same.

Comment: The exact same error "+  $exception {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} System.NullReferenceException
"
The view is commented where the error happens @item.FeeType.FeeTypeName

Comment: Yes! You need to check the value FeeType before render it, Check my updated answer and let me know.

Comment: I cannot do that.
FeeType is not a list

Error CS0019 Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

Comment: Why ? what happen ?? whats the issue ?

Comment: You cannot write that in razor. The syntax is wrong. You cannot do a count on this object because it is not a list.

Comment: Oh! my bad. You are right. Then in this case you dont have FeeType for that memberNumber. Please put a break point in your action method and check whether value is there or not. In case of refresh the whole page, you must be calling some other action method where you must return some record that have FeeType.

Comment: The first Members.Fees[0].FeeType is null. Members.Fees[0].FeeType has the object correctly.

The parent view calls the controller 

        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            Members members = db.Members.Find(id);
            return View(members);
        }

Comment: This works. Now I have to find why the first record is null. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the null type was lazy loading in the end.

I had to requery the db after I had saved the changes and include Fees.FeeTypes to return the correctly populated model.

```
        members = db.Members.Find(fees.MemberNo);
        members.Fees = db.Fees.Include(x => x.FeeType).Where(x => x.Members.MemberNo.Equals(x.MemberNo)).ToList();
```